# Adding a PC to a Windows 2012 R 2 Domain Controller?

Tags: windows

Can I add a PC running Windows 7 with Norton Anti-virus to my Windows 2012 R 2 Domain Controller?

Comment: Depends on what version of Windows 7 you are running, if your running windows 7 home then no, but professional and ultimate can be.

Answer (score 0):

The anti virus software must be uninstalled.  Then add Windows 7 Pro to the Domain Controller. Then reinstall the anti-virus software on the client PC running Windows 7 Pro.